# Fraktur symbols into Entities conversion using perl

Tags: perl, entity

I need to convert the Fraktur symbols into the Named entity:

```
my $input = ", ,  is a symbols of fraktur";
```

Expected Output:

```
$output = "&Afr;, &Bfr;, &Dfr; is a symbols of fraktur";
```

Code:

```
use Win32;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my %fraktursChr = ("&Afr;" => "", "&Bfr;" => "", "&Dfr;" => "");

foreach my $key (keys %fraktursChr)
{
    print "Key: $key-->$fraktursChr{$key}\n ";
    $input=~s/\Q$fraktursChr{$key}\E/$key/g;
}
```

However I couldn't able to replace the symbols using utf8: I would appreciate if someone could help on this one.

Comment: Your expected output is wrong. You're missing semicolons `;` and you have an extra comma that's not in the input.

Comment: @simbabque: I have updated the question

Comment: Tip: `use open ':encoding(utf8)'; binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';` can be written as `use open ':std', ':encoding(utf8)';` (although that also effects STDIN and STDERR).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`use utf8;` needs to be added to tell Perl the source code is encoded using UTF-8.

```
use utf8;                              # Source code is encoded using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';   # Terminal expects/provides UTF-8.

my $input = ",  , is a symbols of fraktur";
my %fraktursChr = ("&Afr;" => "", "&Bfr;" => "", "&Dfr;" => "",);
foreach my $key (keys %fraktursChr)
{
    $input=~s/\Q$fraktursChr{$key}\E/$key/g;
}

print $input;
```

Thanks to [PerlDuck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5830574/perlduck) and [Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross).

Comment: @ikegami: Well Said:

Answer (score 1):

Not actually an answer, but a suggestion for a performance improvement:

```
my $fraktursChr_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %fraktursChr;
my $fraktursChr_re = qr/($fraktursChr_pat)/;

$input =~ s/$fraktursChr_re/$fraktursChr{$1}/g;
```